# How to abort build when compilation of razor views fails?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, project.json

I need to validate razor views during application build, so I used the tool described in the following article:
http://dotnetthoughts.net/compile-your-aspnet-core-mvc-views/
but `postpublish` is too late for me, so I moved `dotnet razor-precompile` into `postcompile` scripts section of `project.json`.

The problem is that even when `razor-precompile` writes some errors on the output, the build is still successful. I need to change this behavior, and I could implement a custom script to do that, but I can't figure out how to manually abort a build.

EDIT: The strange thing is that `dotnet razor-precompile` status code is 1, and it still doesn't make build unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a known issue.

GitHub Issues [2836](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2836),[443](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/443)

As ASP.NET Core is moving from project.json to CSProj, ASP.NET team has closed the issue.